# Why does Start /Wait not wait when used with URLs?

Tags: windows, batch-file

When I'm starting applications from a batch file and I want to wait until the first application finished, I do a start /wait like this, which works fine:

```
start /WAIT "" "notepad.exe"
start /WAIT "" "notepad.exe"
```

While there's no special need for the quotation marks, I made it a habit to use them in order to support commands which have spaces in their path.

Recently I was trying to start a browser via URL and I wanted to wait for the browser to be closed by the user. However, the batch file does not wait when used with URLs like this:

```
start /WAIT "" "http://stackoverflow.com/"
start /WAIT "" "http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

I'm testing this on Windows 7 and my default browser is Firefox.

**Why does waiting not work with URLs and how to Workaround this problem?**

Note: I don't want to start a specific browser. I'd like to let the browser choice up to the user and thus start the default browser. This works:

```
start /WAIT "" "firefox" "http://stackoverflow.com/"
start /WAIT "" "firefox" "http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

Comment: Firefox is a single instance application, so opening the URL did not launch a new process, so there is nothing to wait for.

Comment: On my PC Firefox is started several times.

Comment: If you look in task manager you'll see that there is just one Firefox process that is handling all those windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem to be because it is launching a program by using 'filetype' association and the `/w` isn't implemented in that mode.

I think the only workaround is to read the registry to detect the default browser and path and then launch that browser with the URL, so the `/w` will be functional.

Comment: Would that mean the HTTP protcol handler is the program being started and waited for? The protocol handler starts Firefox and then exits? On one hand side, that would make sense...

Comment: @ThomasW. For information about how the OS starts the default web browser on url invocation (the article is for C++ developers, but behaviour is the same), see [Use ShellExecute to launch the default Web browser](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816/en-us).

Answer (score 0):

Start /Wait
The /WAIT option should reverse the default 'run in parallel' behaviour of START but again your results will vary depending on the item being started, for example:

Echo Starting
START /wait "demo" calc.exe
Echo Done
The above will start the calculator and wait before continuing. However if you replace calc.exe with Winword.exe, to run Word instead, then the /wait will stop working, this is because Winword.exe is a stub which launches the main Word application and then exits.

A similar problem will occur when starting a batch file, by default START will run the equivalent of CMD /K which opens a second command window and leaves it open. In most cases you will want the batch script to complete and then just close it's CMD console to resume the initial batch script. This can be done by explicitly running CMD /C ...

Echo Starting
START /wait "demo" CMD /c demoscript.cmd
Echo Done
Add /B to have everything run in a single window.

In a batch file, an alternative is to use TIMEOUT to delay processing of individual commands.